# Receive two ajax json Data from .net and use 'data.jsonA.testName'

Tags: javascript, .net, json

i use .net and send js(ajax) two data to .net controller
in data test1 and test2 is json data.

```
.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/test/test_Put/",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {jsonA:JSON.stringify(test1), jsonB:JSON.stringify(test2)},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

.net controller

```
public class testTwo
{
    public test1 jsonA;
    public test2 jsonB;
}

public class testA
{
    public int node1;
    public string testName1;
}

public class testB
{
    public int node2;
    public string testName2;
}


[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult test_Put([FromBody]testTwo tt){
       Console.WriteLine(tt.jsonA.testName1);
}
```

i saw error by data.jsonA.testName it's Invalid usage? i've also tried serialization

Comment: Still not properly sending json to server. To send json should be `data:JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: sorry i dont understand. There was no problem in other circumstances.
ajax send data is this
jsonA: "{"test":0,"tt":4,"test1":null}"
jsonB: "{"test":"aa","tt":"","test1":""}

Comment: Ok then you are using wrong contentType. Just because a property has a json string as value the overall contentType is not json

Comment: i solved this problem. tkx for u kindness and help